# Laravel using select2 plagin and change app.js in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, jquery-select2

I have aproblem. I built a project using Laravel 5.8 and it depends on the select2 plugin. I did everything correctly. But after compiling the project

```
npm run dev
```

I have the following exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
```

I know what has to be done. `jQuery` is connecting twice in this project. At first in my `.blade.php`:

```
{{asset('adminlte/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')}}
```

and a second time after compiling (`npm run dev`), the Laravel, by itself, does it in `public/js/app.js`

```
  window.$ = window.jQuery = 
  __webpack_require__(/*! jquery */ "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js");
```

If I delete this code, I don't see the issue and select2 works correctly. 
Here is the compiled code from `public/js/app.js`

[image: two muppets]

It says: code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.

Does anyone know how to hide this line after compilation?

Or should I delete this code after each compiling turn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove it from the source file which is at `resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js` and compile it again with `npm run dev`.

Or you could just import select2 inside that file so the user has to download fewer files.

You should never modify the compiled files in `public/` since the changes will disappear after compilation.